# What is wrong with my recursive visiting function?

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm trying to write a small snippet that calculates the shortest way thru a series of points.

Here's the code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class Waypoint
    {
        public Point P;
        public bool Visited;
    }

    public class Point
    {
        public double X;
        public double Y;

        public Point(double x, double y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

    class Program
    {
        static List<Point> AllPoints = new List<Point>();
        static Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        static Point endPoint = new Point(4, 3);
        static List<List<Waypoint>> weightedList = new List<List<Waypoint>>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(0, 0));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(1, 1));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(1, 2));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(1, 3));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(2, 2));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(2, 3));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(3, 2));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(3, 3));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(4, 3));

            // select all points within reach, its a 1x1 square between points so the max     distance is 1.42
            var filteredList = from p in AllPoints
                where DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(p, startPoint) < 1.42 && p.X !=     startPoint.X && p.Y != startPoint.Y
                select p;

            List<Waypoint> currList = new List<Waypoint>();
            currList.Add(new Waypoint() { P = new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y), Visited =     true });

            foreach (var p in filteredList)
            {
                currList.Add(new Waypoint() { P = new Point(p.X, p.Y), Visited = true });

                RecusivlyVisitPoint(currList[currList.Count-1], currList);
            }
        }

        static void RecusivlyVisitPoint(Waypoint wp, List<Waypoint> list)
        {
            // we have reached the end
            if (wp.P == endPoint)
            {
                weightedList.Add(list);

                return;
            }

            // select all points within reach, its a 1x1 square between points so the max     distance is 1.42
            List<Point> allPointsWithInReach = (from p in AllPoints
                where DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(p, wp.P) < 1.42
                select p).ToList<Point>();

            // filter with already visited
            for (int k = allPointsWithInReach.Count<Point>()-1; k >= 0; k--)
            {
                Point p = allPointsWithInReach[k];

                foreach (var lP in list)
                    if (lP.P == p)
                        allPointsWithInReach.RemoveAt(k);
            }

            // there are no other points to go thru
            if (allPointsWithInReach.Count == 0)
            {
                weightedList.Add(list);

                return;
            }

            // recursivly go thru the list
            foreach (var p in allPointsWithInReach)
            {
                List<Waypoint> newList = new List<Waypoint>();
                foreach (var e in list)
                    newList.Add(e);

                newList.Add(new Waypoint() { P = new Point(p.X, p.Y), Visited = true });

                RecusivlyVisitPoint(newList[newList.Count - 1], newList);
            }
        }

        static double DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X), 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p1.Y -     p2.Y), 2));
        }
    }
}
```

It's a 1x1 "grid" so as you can see I filter possible points from current standing point by distance of 1.42 and not already visited.

The problem here is that its running thru all the points, returning all points at if `(wp.P == endPoint)`. What have I missed? I created a new list and sends it further down the recursion for each node.

At the end, not implemented, im going to sum up all the list items in each list in `weightedList` and choose the one with the fewest elements.

Comment: Do you ever check which of the possible next visited points is closest to the endPoint and select THAT point as the next point?

Comment: Do I need to? Sure, in my example one result would go thru all the points, but one result should also be the shortest way?

Answer (score 0):

First, when I tried to run your code, I saw that this code :

```
for (int k = allPointsWithInReach.Count<Point>()-1; k >= 0; k--)
{
    Point p = allPointsWithInReach[k];

    foreach (var lP in list)
        if (lP.P == p)
            allPointsWithInReach.RemoveAt(k);
}
```

isn't removing any of the point you have already gone to. So that means it went on an infinite loop and created a stackoverflow exception.

I removed the points you went with linq wich is more concise. In order to do that I needed to evaluate if 2 points were equals so I added 2 methods in the point class. 
Here's the code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Waypoint
    {
        public Point P;
        public bool Visited;
    }
    public class Point : IEquatable<Point>
    {
        public double X;
        public double Y;

        public Point(double x, double y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        public bool Equals(Point other)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

            return X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int hashX = X.GetHashCode();

            int hashY = Y.GetHashCode();

            return hashX ^ hashY;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static List<Point> AllPoints = new List<Point>();
        static Point startPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        static Point endPoint = new Point(4, 3);
        static List<List<Waypoint>> weightedList = new List<List<Waypoint>>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(0, 0));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(1, 1));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(1, 2));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(1, 3));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(2, 2));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(2, 3));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(3, 2));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(3, 3));
            AllPoints.Add(new Point(4, 3));

            // select all points within reach, its a 1x1 square between points so the max distance is 1.42
            var filteredList = from p in AllPoints
                     where DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(p, startPoint) < 1.42 && p.X != startPoint.X && p.Y != startPoint.Y
                     select p;

            List<Waypoint> currList = new List<Waypoint>();
            currList.Add(new Waypoint() { P = new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y), Visited = true });

            foreach (var p in filteredList)
            {
                currList.Add(new Waypoint() { P = new Point(p.X, p.Y), Visited = true });

                RecusivlyVisitPoint(currList.Last(), currList);
            }
            var min = weightedList.OrderBy(w => w.Count).Take(1).ToList();
        }

        static void RecusivlyVisitPoint(Waypoint wp, List<Waypoint> list)
        {
            // we have reached the end
            if (wp.P.Equals(endPoint))
            {
                weightedList.Add(list);

                return;
            }

            // select all points within reach, its a 1x1 square between points so the max distance is 1.42
            var allPointsWithInReach = AllPoints.FindAll(p => DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(p, wp.P) < 1.42);

            // filter with already visited
            allPointsWithInReach = allPointsWithInReach.Except(list.Select(w => w.P)).ToList();

            // there are no other points to go thru
            if (allPointsWithInReach.Count == 0)
            {
                //weightedList.Add(list);
                // but you didn't get trough the end so it's not a possibility
                return;
            }

            // recursivly go thru the list
            foreach (var p in allPointsWithInReach)
            {
                List<Waypoint> newList = new List<Waypoint>();
                foreach (var e in list)
                    newList.Add(e);

                newList.Add(new Waypoint() { P = new Point(p.X, p.Y), Visited = true });

                RecusivlyVisitPoint(newList.Last(), newList);
            }
        }

        static double DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X), 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y), 2));
        }
    }
}
```